# I wonder if this is Python IDLE

Tags: python-3.x, linux, python-idle

At first, I'm not good at English but I'm doing my best, thank you.

I connected Amazon Lightsail and installed python36.

It is the list I installed.

- python36.x86_64
- python36-devel.x86_64
- python36-libs.x86_64
- python36-pip.noarch

Then I entered shell as shown in picture below after typing 'python3'.
[image]

At https://realpython.com/python-idle/#what-is-python-idle, How to Use the Python IDLE Shell's first image, it looks very similar to the image I uploaded.

So I think it is Python IDLE but I'm not sure yet.

Because at https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=53908, 'python34-tools' contains idle3.

What? I'm not installed 'python36-tools'!

I installed 'python36-tools' and typed 'idle3' but there's an error, 'command not found'.

Even according to https://centos.pkgs.org/7/puias-unsupported-x86_64/python36-idle-3.6.6-1.sdl7.x86_64.rpm.html, it is definitely Python IDLE!

What's the right thing? I'm so confused.

I wanted to know more, so visit https://docs.python.org/ko/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html and find this, 'The IDLE features formerly implemented as extensions have been reimplemented as normal features.'

It can be translated like this?

'Starting with version 3.6.3, you don't have to install idle3 separately. Just type python3 for use Python IDLE.'

I searched the information related to the above and couldn't find anything.

Please help me!

Comment: check where "idlelib" is located usually it contains idle.pyw

Comment: IDLE is a GUI application consisting of multiple windows. Typing ``python3`` in a terminal just gives you an interactive python shell. What you have there is not IDLE.

Comment: Thank you so much guys, Now it's clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDLE is a GUI application, with menus and windows. So you need to use a Linux/macos/windows desktop environment, it does not run in a terminal window.

It actually looks like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bOvqYw1SZJg

It starts in a standard python interactive shell, such as your screen shot.
But being a desktop app, it allows you to have multiple editor windows open with source files, and it has GUI debugging tools. IDLE is rudimentary, but also very simple (which can be a good thing).

I think there is a lot to be said for learning python in a real desktop environment, with multiple windows and friendly, easy to use debuggers.

There are cloud IDEs for python, but I don't think they are a good step for newcomers. The debugging is not very good, for instance.

However, `jupyter` is a good option for learning python, I think.

E.g.: https://realpython.com/jupyter-notebook-introduction/

Jupyter runs a webserver and you edit python in interactive workbooks which you open in a browser. I suppose it is a cloud IDE.

This is a short video of running it on Windows ...  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZ952vChhuI
jump to about the 2m mark to see it running.

To be honest, it is arguably a better place to start than IDLE.You could run the server part of this from lightsail, but you will probably need to configure your lightsail instance to open the ports needed to server jupyter's web pages.

But if you want to start with IDLE, you need python running on a desktop. A linux desktop is a very good choice. You can set up a desktop linux, such as ubuntu, in virtualbox if all you have is Windows.

However, if after all of that, you are going to do python from the command line, you should learn about
* virtual environments 
* once you set one up, do `pip install ipython`to get a better version of the python shell.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, `python3` on a non-Windows command line starts python in interactive mode.  To start IDLE on a command line, use `python3 -m idlelib`.